# Powershell - Problem with Start-transcript using remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have a file transcript-test.ps1 with below contents

> $log="TestLog{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmm}" -f
>   (Get-Date) $logfile =
>   'C:\logs\'+$log+'.txt'
>   Start-transcript -path $logfile -force
>   Write-host "To test if this message gets logged"
>   Stop-transcript

I try to run the script from lets say "box1" and the log file contains the below contents

> **************** Windows PowerShell Transcript Start Start
>   time: 20110105114050 Username  :
>   domain\user  Machine    : BOX1
>   (Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service
>   Pack 2) 
>   ********************** Transcript started, output file is
>   C:\logs\TestLog20110105-1140.txt
>
> To test if this message gets logged
>
> **************** Windows PowerShell Transcript End End time:
>   20110105114050
>
> ---

When I run the same script from another machine using below script I don't see any messages in the log file

> Invoke-command {powershell.exe
>   -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -File C:\in ll\transcript-test.ps1} -computername
>   box1 -credential $credential get-credential

Contents of log file :

> **************** Windows PowerShell Transcript Start Start
>   time: 20110105114201 Username  :
>   DOMAIN\user  Machine    : BOX1
>   (Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service
>   Pack 2)
>
> ---
>
> **************** Windows PowerShell Transcript End End time:
>   20110105114201
>
> ---

Is there anyway to log the messages from the script to log file when invoked remotely ?

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

The following will capture your local and remote verbose messages in the transcript

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
Start-Transcript -path c:\temp\transcript.txt 

Write-Verbose "here 1"

$job = Invoke-Command cbwfdev01 -ScriptBlock {

    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    $VerbosePreference = "continue";

    Write-Verbose "there 1";
    Write-Verbose "there 2";
    Write-Verbose "there 3";

} -AsJob 

Wait-Job $job | Out-Null

$VerboseMessages = $job.ChildJobs[0].verbose.readall()

ForEach ($oneMessage In $VerboseMessages) {Write-Verbose $oneMessage}

Write-Verbose "here 2"

Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-command execute your code into a job, which is as far as I understant a thread with no console, so no transcription. For me what you got is absolutly normal.